# Nested Dictionaries Golang Trouble

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, struct, go

Go Code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    _ "bytes"
    "fmt"
    _ "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"
    _ "reflect"
    "regexp"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var (
    LocalDirectory   = "s3logs" // Into this directory
    Lock             sync.Mutex
    totalImpressions int
)

var data = make(map[string]map[string]int)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    // by adding this line i'm telling the program to run the threads on 4 different cores at the same time, Parallelism!!
    //REMEMBER TO ADD BLOCKS TO STOP RACE CONDITIONS
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var year, month, day = time.Now().Date()
    str_year := strconv.Itoa(year)
    str_month := strconv.Itoa(int(month))
    str_day := strconv.Itoa(day)

    if int(month) < 10 {
        str_month = "0" + strconv.Itoa(int(month))
    }
    if day < 10 {
        str_day = "0" + strconv.Itoa(day)
    }

    regBuckets := map[string]string{
        "us-west-1": "pubgears-ca",
        "test":      "test",
    }

    for region, bucket := range regBuckets {
        prefix := fmt.Sprintf("tagserver/logs/AWSLogs/978380792767/elasticloadbalancing/%s/%s/%s/%s/", region, str_year, str_month, str_day)
        wg.Add(1)
        go getLogs(region, bucket, LocalDirectory+bucket, &prefix, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    //salon/t1/728x90/index
    //totalImpressions := 0
    // var provider = make(map[string]int)
    // for key, value := range data {
    //   key = strings.TrimSpace(key)
    //   pro := strings.Split(key, "_")[3]
    //
    //   if strings.Contains(pro, "pp") == true || (pro == "pulsepoint") || (pro == "cweb") {
    //     provider["pulsepoint"] += value
    //   } else if (pro == "openx") || (pro == "openx3") {
    //     provider["openx"] += value
    //   } else if key == " " {
    //     continue
    //   } else {
    //     provider[pro] += value
    //   }
    //   totalImpressions += value
    // }

    for tag, value := range data {
        for hour, imp := range value {
            fmt.Printf("tag: %s  \n hour: %s impression %s\n", tag, hour, imp)
        }
    }

    //sl = sl[:len(sl)-1]

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("\nTime took %s\n", elapsed)

}

func getLogs(region string, bucket string, directory string, prefix *string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    sess := session.New()
    client := s3.New(sess, &aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})

    params := &s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: &bucket, Prefix: prefix}
    manager := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(client, func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
        d.PartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024 // 6MB per part
        d.Concurrency = 4
    })
    d := downloader{bucket: bucket, dir: directory, Downloader: manager}
    client.ListObjectsPages(params, d.eachPage)
    wg.Done()
}

// downloader object and methods
type downloader struct {
    *s3manager.Downloader
    bucket, dir string
}

func (d *downloader) eachPage(page *s3.ListObjectsOutput, more bool) bool {
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        // fmt.Println(obj)
        //     return true
        d.downloadToFile(*obj.Key)
    }
    return true
}

func (d *downloader) downloadToFile(key string) {
    // Create the directories in the path
    // desktop path
    user, errs := user.Current()
    if errs != nil {
        panic(errs)
    }
    homedir := user.HomeDir
    desktop := homedir + "/Desktop/" + d.dir
    file := filepath.Join(desktop, key)
    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(file), 0775); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Setup the local file
    fd, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    // Download the file using the AWS SDK
    //fmt.Printf("Downloading s3://%s/%s to %s...\n", d.bucket, key, file)
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: &d.bucket, Key: &key}
    d.Download(fd, params)
    _, e := d.Download(fd, params)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    tag := regexp.MustCompile("/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)")
    date := regexp.MustCompile("T([^:]+)")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    // HAVING TROUBLE HERE
    for scanner.Scan() {
        //dateCollection := make(map[string]int)
        m := tag.FindString(scanner.Text())
        if m != "" {
            // stop races
            Lock.Lock()
            arr := strings.Split(m, "/")
            taghash := strings.Join(arr, "_")
            taghash = strings.TrimLeft(taghash, "_")
            //data[taghash]++
            m = date.FindString(scanner.Text())
            if m != "" {
                hour := m
                data[taghash] = make(map[string]int)
                data[taghash][hour]++
            }
            Lock.Unlock()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(file)
    os.Remove(file)
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The area i'm having trouble at starts on line 167 section below:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
        //dateCollection := make(map[string]int)
        m := tag.FindString(scanner.Text())
        if m != "" {
            // stop races
            Lock.Lock()
            arr := strings.Split(m, "/")
            taghash := strings.Join(arr, "_")
            taghash = strings.TrimLeft(taghash, "_")
            //data[taghash]++
            m = date.FindString(scanner.Text())
            if m != "" {
                hour := m
                data[taghash] = make(map[string]int)
                data[taghash][hour]++
            }
            Lock.Unlock()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(file)
    os.Remove(file)
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

The output i'm getting when I print the values in the main func

```
fstvt1_ros_300x600_pp8_1 T07 1
```

I'm expecting an output that looks something like this:

```
fstvt1_ros_300x600_pp8_1
T00 213434
T01 23432
T02 3324
T03 324
T04 324
T05 0 ...
(this isn't real data)
```

**What I'm trying to do:**
I have a map of data `var data = make(map[string]map[string]int)` whose key is equal to a taghash, e.g. `fstvt1_ros_300x600_pp8_1`. The value is a map of data.  The key value of that map is expected to be a string and an integer. I want multiple maps.  One for each key... T01, T02..  What is currently outputted is the last item in the last of items i'm iterating on instead of a collection of keys and values for each taghash.  How do i make is so that instead of overwriting the data, it adds the new key Value T01, T02.. and if the taghash and hour are the some to increment that particular object.

Line of code i'm currently using:

T01, T02..

```
data[taghash][hour]++
```

Where the if the taghash and hour exist then it should increment.  If the taghash and hour doesn't exist then create the taghash and add the new key and increment.

Comment: I might work on an answer if I have a bit more time later but a few things that might help... Firstly there is no dictionary type in Go, it's a map, secondly the data you have in plain text is not consistent with the map type. You said you have a dictionary with a single key with a collection of dictionaries? No you don't. The `foobar_openx` has an object for the value and that object contains two unnamed objects. You don't have keys, so you certainly don't have a map. The nearest structure to what you posted is an array or slice.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, I'm away Go uses maps, my think dictionary when I'm playing with maps (key: value).  In python my values would be a collection of dictionaries, where each dictionary has a key that is the hour and value of impressions.  So i'll fix the structure right now, I see my mistake.  Even so, that was a typing error i'm my part, the go code doesn't reflect that.

Comment: The inner most objects should just be `type Views struct { hours, impressions int }` and `foobar_openx` should just be a slice or array of that type; `[]Views`. Are you trying to parse the data you posted? Is there a reason you're not just using json? Why that format? It is similar to json but I don't believe that is valid json (neither a dictionary nor an array therefor you're missing keys for values).

Comment: I suppose i'm not using a Json because Python dictionaries and Json are near identical in structure.  The format is important because the end result will be to interact with a python created mongo collection.

Comment: Python collections follow very loose conventions, collections in Go do not. You're never going to store that data in a map because you do not have keys for the inner most objects. The inner objects could be represented as a map, but why? All that does is make it so you have to add error checking every where you do access or risk a runtime error when data is absent.

Comment: There is a mongo package for Go. JSON is just a format for representing data, it has no connection to dictionaries in Python. The Python type is accepting of just about anything, it would benefit you to understand the json's structure specifically because once again, even in json it is not a dictionary. They have arrays and dictionaries and objects, and what you have in json and in Go is never a dictionary.

Comment: The structure I portrayed above is exactly how it looks in the python version of the script, I suppose then that I need help creating the equivocalancy in Go.. or as close to that as possible

Comment: No offense but you simply need to learn about data structures because the thing you're referring to in Python again, is very fast and loose with it's conventions and clearly you don't actually understand the structure of your data which is going to be necessary in Go because it's conventions are strict, as are json's. The structure you portrays above is a text representation of data and in no way corresponds to how that data is represented in a program. The collection you're using in Python is super abstracted, there's a lot more to it than what you posted above, that's what it prints for you.

Comment: No offense taken, I work with data structures all day in python and javascript.  I just moved to go, so it's more of a syntactical thing then my knowledge.  I updated the data structure above, to reflect what i'm trying to get done.  I assume the closest thing in go is something like this var data = make(map[string]map[string]int)...which i've tried...but i can't seem to get right

Comment: Taking this out with you, I think I see what I did wrong. I'm going to try it 
hour := m
    data[taghash] = make(map[string]int)
    data[taghash][hour]++

Comment: No sorry you're not getting it... JavaScript and Python are dynamically typed languages and the collections you work with are ubiquitous and work for everything, this is not the case in Go. It's not just syntax. The collection in Python has features of arrays, linked lists, and dictionaries all in one and you can store pretty much anything in it. In Go things are explicit. You need to know the structure of the data in a more descriptive manner in order to represent it in code, you can't just declare the end all be all of types and say "Read data" and have it work.

Comment: Okay I made some updates to my code, I'm going to post them in a second...hopefully something can help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from

```
data[taghash] = make(map[string]int)
```

This sets `data[taghash]` to a newly allocated map every time through. That's definitely not what you're trying to do. Instead:

```
if _, ok := data[taghash]; !ok {
    // data[taghash] does not exist -- create it!
    data[taghash] := make(map[string]int)
}
data[taghash][hour]++
```

This is equivalent to:

```
# Python
data.setdefault(taghash, {}).setdefault(hour, 0) += 1
```

Or

```
if taghash not in data:
    data[taghash] = {}
if hour not in data[taghash]:
    data[taghash][hour] = 1
else:
    data[taghash][hour] += 1
```

Comment: I've changed the structure of the code.  I also, don't know the cap, so the code would have to go to handle an unknown amount of data (grow on it's own.)

Comment: @msanti it does, `cap` is just an efficiency issue with slices. There's a cost to growing the slice (since it has to allocate a new backing array)

Comment: also, each hour should be it's own key. so that it can be accessed like data[taghash][hour] -> impression #,  the code i've posted above provides the structure I just need to figure out why its not adding values correctly.

Comment: Note that I agree completely with @evanmcdonnal in the question comments that your data structure could use work. This should do lookups to `hash+hour -> views` very quickly, but only if you already have a hash and hour. Actually pulling data out of this map will be very difficult compared to Python.

Comment: Thank for you're help. Could you explain this line to me if _, ok := data[taghash]; !ok, logically it makes sense, but i'm new to go and i've no come across this syntax before.

Comment: @msanti there's a couple things going on there. There's the `if <initialization statement>; <condition> {...}` syntax and there's the `value, ok := mapping[key]` syntax. The former allows you to write a statement to initialize the `if` block (not unlike the first statement in a `for i:=0; i < 10; i++` block. The latter lets you pull the value from a mapping and ensure that it exists by checking `ok`. We don't actually care about the value here, so we use the empty variable to blank it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99229/discussion-between-adam-smith-and-msanti).